# how to preserve a variable value and use it globally in logstash

Tags: logstash-grok

I have a variable 'worflow' in the code and once any event matches that filter I want to preserve it for next events as it is.
Problem - By using 'add field', for the event which actually contains workflow the value of workflow is displayed in csv, but for other events %{workflow} (as it is ) is displayed.
Please suggest any way for this.

```
input { 
    file{
        path => "D:/alerts extracted from mails/*.log"
        start_position => beginning
        sincedb_path=>"NUL"
    }
}
filter {
   grok{
 match=> {"message" => "(?<mess_time>%{DAY} %{MONTH} %{MONTHDAY} %{TIME} %{YEAR}) : %{DATA:Title}> %{WORD:Code} Workflow: (\[%{WORD:workflow}\]) %{GREEDYDATA:info}"}
 match=> {"message" => "(?<mess_time>%{DAY} %{MONTH} %{MONTHDAY} %{TIME} %{YEAR}) : %{DATA:Title}> %{WORD:Code} %{GREEDYDATA:info}"}
}

if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags]{
     drop { }
     }
     mutate {

        add_field => { "client_id" => "BP" }
        add_field => { "portfolio_id" => "NAGP" }
        add_field => { "resource_id" => " " }
        add_field => { "resource_name" => "%{workflow}" }
        add_field => { "lob" => "creditrisk" }
        add_field => { "mess" => "%{info} }
    }
    }

output{

csv{

fields =>["client_id","portfolio_id","resouce_id","resource_name","lob","mess_time","mess"]
path => "C:/Users/saavi.verma/Downloads/logstash-7.6.2/output_files/output1.csv"
}
}
```

Comment: Please help !!!!

Comment: Please refer to this question posted on DiscussElastic: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/keeping-global-variables-in-ls/39908/4 . In my opinion you should find everything you need to achieve your goals there. Hope this helps you.